# jqplot - x-axis

Tags: jqplot

I have a long list of data for x-axis data when drawing a line chart (about 800 entries).  The problem is it will not display correctly and overwrite each other.  I am thinking a way to show (for example, every one hundred for a grid) and don't know how to do it.  Please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify an array of ticks to display on your chosen axis :

```
var xTicks = new Array(1,101,201,301,401,501,601,701,800);
--In your plot, add ticks option to your  chosen axis :
axes: {
 xaxis: {
  ticks: xTicks --my ticks array
  renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
  autoscale: false
 }
}
```

It should do the trick.

Comment: The problem is line chart becomes flat.  Below are data that I used.

Comment: var line1 = [766 ,829 ,821 ,905 ,837 ,940 ,984 ,1081 ,1112 ,1205 ,1241 ,1260 ,1293 ,1453 ,1602 ,1828 ,1953 ,2229 ,2366 ,2648 ,2788 ,3125 ,3374 ,3851 ,4127 ,4495 ,5141 ,6040 ,6289 ,6551 ,6698 ,7144];
 
  var xticks = new Array(24,18,12,0);
 
  var plot1 = $.jqplot('chartD', [line1],

Comment: A spare solution can be not to display point label (using series: {pointLabels: {show: false}}) and to display tooltip only with y-axis values (using highlighter: {show: true, tooltipAxes: 'y', tooltipLocation: 'n'})